# How to pass resolved promise to a scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I started using AngularJS and currently looking at promises. So my old code looks like this:

```
app.controller('CustomerController', function ($scope Customers, $q) {
    init();

    function init() {
        Customers.getCustomers()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.customers = response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});

app.factory('Customers', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/customers');
        }
    };
});
```

So what I did in my init function to make a promise is like this:

```
function init() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Customers.getCustomers()
    .then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data); // how to pass this into my scope?
    }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
     return deferred.promise;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not able to pass it to my scope. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you need some data from an API when you need to init your controller, consider using ngRoute or uiRouter `resolve` attribute instead of manually calling an initialization function in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do here. But it doesn't make sense to use promises like this in controller. You would need to call your init function somewhere else like this:

```
init().then(response => $scope.data = response);
```

In your old code in factory the get method of $http service is returning a promise and you correctly handle the response in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the $http service from Angular, already returns a promise. The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service.
So you could have something like this:

```
app.controller('CustomerController', function ($scope, Customers) {
    init();

    function init() {
        Customers.getCustomers()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.customers = data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});

app.factory('Customers', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function () {
            var promise = $http.get('/api/customers').
                then(function(response){
                        return response.data;
                    }, 
                    function(error) {
                        return response.error;
                    }
                )

            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```